# Not displaying certain trigger severities during maintenance mode

Tags: zabbix

During the weekly updating of all our servers and services, our Zabbix dashboard becomes flooded with 'Information' triggers. Whilst you can manually disable these from being displayed by editing the 'Problems' widget on the dashboard, I cannot seem to find a function to only disable these when maintenance mode is enabled.

Is there a way to enable this or change the maintenance mode settings to prevent it from displaying these triggers?

I'm running Zabbix 4.0.0

Comment: Which version of Zabbix? Does your dashboard show problems/triggers in maintenance?

Comment: The version 4.0. It does show triggers in maintenance mode as I've enabled 'Display suppressed problems'.

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to have a separate threshold limit when in maintenance. You can hide information & "not classified" severities completely, but that will not change depending on the maintenance status. Perhaps it's worth creating a feature request (if no existing requests found).